# How to use next() structure in nodejs with express

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express with node.

I need use a module('authenticationJwt') to authenticate a user and call it in other module('user').

I am using the next code, but after call the authentication module, the app never continues to next structure in the calling module.
For sample, im my app console.log('conv') is never called.

if I use the sintax:

```
router.get('/nome/:id',auth.isAuthenticated,async function(req, res, next)....
```

It works, but I have many gets and posts and I´d like to authenticate all routes into module globally instead of individually.

What am I doing wrong?

//user module

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth=require('./authenticationJwt'); 

router.use(auth.isAuthenticated);
router.get('/nome/:id',async function(req, res, next) {
    //never is called
    console.log('conv');
})
module.exports=router;
```

//authenticationJwt module

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // Import JWT Package
const auth = {}
const secret = 'asdsad'; // Create custom secret for use in JWT

auth.isAuthenticated=function(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.header('Authorization')) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'No token provided' }); // Return error if no token was provided in the request
        }

        var token = req.header('Authorization').split(' ')[1];
        // Check if token is valid and not expired  
        if (token) {
            // Function to verify token
            jwt.verify(token, secret, function(err, decoded) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Token invalid' }); // Token has expired or is invalid
                } else {
                    req.decoded = decoded; // Assign to req. variable to be able to use it in next() route ('/me' route)
                    next(); // Required to leave middleware
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'No token provided' }); // Return error if no token was provided in the request
        }
};
module.exports=auth;
```

Comment: I think that you have to actually call the middleware like a function, either `const auth=require('./authenticationJwt')();` or `router.use(auth.isAuthenticated());`

Comment: You should try out this link. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html Which explains how you can define route level middleware as well as router level middleware.